# How to use cat to lowercase large files in bash?

Tags: bash, cat, tr

I'm using the following command to lowercase all characters in a text file.

```
CORPUSLOWER=$(cat foobar.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
echo $CORPUSLOWER > foobar.txt
```

The problem, however, is that `foobar.txt` is about 20gig big and it only replaces a small chunk of the `foobar.txt` file.

My question: how can I use bash to convert a large file to lowercase?

Comment: Maybe using just  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'  < foobar.txt > newfile.txt, use less memory

Comment: ([Useless use of cat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat))

Comment: Also, useless use of variable capture. Attempting to read the entire file into a shell variable just so you can `echo` it to standard output is pretty pointless, seeing as `tr` itself already is capable of printing its result to standard output (and not much else in fact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible by

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < foobar.txt | dd of=foobar.txt conv=notrunc
```

Or (which might be cleaner), use a temporary file

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `sponge` from moreutils, you can do:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < foobar.txt | sponge foobar.txt
```

`sponge` "soaks up" all the contents and only opens the file when it saw the end of the file.

Comment: If you dont have that `tail -n 10000000000` works well in general, though the corpus file might be huge. Is it only 1 line?

Comment: jep, that is helpful, thanks